# Local Storage Problem > ME I cant seem to make this work

Tags: javascript

Problem: Local Storage is not storing data.

I am working on a daily scheduler app for my bootcamp. I am trying to use local storage to keep data on the app. However when I refresh, the data disappears. I included the code I am using that i am working with. Let me know if you can show me where I am going wrong.

Thanks so much!

Cheers

```js
// Background Color Set Function

// define row is time in 24 hour time format
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
let currentHour = parseInt(moment().format('H'));

// lets make sure we are getting expected output
console.log(currentHour);


Array.from(rows).forEach(row => {
  let
    rowIdString = row.id,
    rowHour;
  if (rowIdString) {
    rowHour = parseInt(rowIdString);
  }
  if (rowHour) {
    // Compares row id to current hour and sets color accordingly
    if (currentHour === rowHour) {
      setColor(row, "red");
    } else if ((currentHour < rowHour)) {
      setColor(row, "green");
    } else {
      setColor(row, "lightgrey");
    }
  }
});

function setColor(element, color) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}


var input = document.getElementById('textArea6').value;
localStorage.setItem('text6', input);

document.getElementById('textArea6').value = localStorage.getItem('text6');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  ;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06AED5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-8">
```

Comment: `// ******* Local Storage Function  *******`  Is there supposed to be a function definition below that line?  I see two lines of code, but it isn't clear if they're inside a function or not.

Comment: You have a script tag *above* the HTML tag?  That simply isn't valid, at all.  Script tags must go inside `body` or `head`.

Comment: You have a `submit` button *outside* of a form.  That should probably be changed to `button` or removed entirely, though I'm not sure if it qualifies as a problem.

Comment: @Amy I think that that is just because the OP used some of the snippet's function to add the jQuery library.

Comment: You have no `body`, all of your content is inside the head.  It should be inside the body.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to use as little code as possible and made some bad edits.  I just uploaded my entire code this time,

Comment: Again, sorry for the mix up with the code in the beginning. I learned what I did wrong, and I appreciate everyone's input.  On to learning more about how to become a jr dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is (beside the HTML) that you're storing the value of the text area to localStorage as soon as the page is loaded, you should probably store it when the button is clicked (when its `onclick` callback function is executed), here is an example:

```
function setColor(element, color) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

function save_data() {
  var input = document.getElementById('textArea6').value;
  localStorage.setItem('text6', input);
}

document.getElementById('textArea6').value = localStorage.getItem('text6');
```

Now, when the page is loaded, the value of the `#textArea6` `<textarea>` is set to the `text6` value from the `localStorage` and when the `save_data` function is executed, the value of this text area is saved to `localStorage` under the same property name.

Comment: `save_data` has to be accessible from window (has to be declared outside of any other function).